# Copy and paste issue with Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: firefox, libreoffice, 19.10, copy, paste

Since updating on Ubuntu 19.10 I have to copy a text twice to insert it. This issue occurs when I want to copy a password from a file opened inside LibreOffice Writer to Firefox.

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: Is it everywhere or just few applications concerned (terminal, text editor, ...) ?

Comment: its with libre office writer and firefox. i have a passwort list with writer and i always copy and paste the data into the firefox account logins ^^ but what i found its not happening with the irc client HexChat actually.

Comment: I use parcellite which stores the last n lines of the clipboard.. so I wonder if your first copy shows up in that. it is bad security, but you could use that to store your passwords if it works better.                                                                                                          
     sudo  apt install parcellite

Comment: related in libreoffice https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mutter/+bug/1852183

Comment: I've read in a couple of places that it could be a Wayland problem

Comment: I'm having the same issue on tow systems with several applications, and i'm running X11

Comment: I have the same issue too and it seems to matter little if it's in a native Ubuntu app or in a Windows Wine app. Coping two or more times, after deselecting and reselecting, will usually get the text to be copied but I spend more time doing that than getting any actual work done! This is a known bug with Ubuntu 19.10 which apparently uses a different clipboard than previous versions (I have no idea why a working clipboard was replaced by one that's broken) and I hope it's fixed soon. In the meantime, is there any way to install another, alternate clipboard?

Answer (score 7):

Same issue here in Ubuntu 19.10, apparently because of the new clipboard manager on the mutter 3.34.  This bug already has been reported on launchpad (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mutter/+bug/1852183) and should be fixed in gtk3 3.24.13 and mutter 3.34.2.

Comment: How does one install the fixed gtk? Most things I've found online seem to be referring to old versions so were not clear.

Comment: @DonP Unfortunately, this was not fixed yet, even in mutter 3.34.3 version. The upstream bug is https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/mutter/issues/919. You can add (at your own risk) the developer repositories in the software&updates program on Ubuntu and upgrade the mutter version if you like.

Comment: Thank you and it seems to have nothing whatsoever to do with LibreOffice as the original poster suggested. It happens in any application I use but it isn't consistent.  Usually it takes two copy attempts but sometimes the first one does the job. This is a major problem that makes my work take twice as long as it should so, as much as I hate it, I may have to switched to Windows for a while so that I can get things done until this has been sorted out.

Comment: It does it with anything so changing apps won’t fix something that is clearly broken at the most basic level.